# How to play a video automatically in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to play automatic video instead of a picture on my flutter page, I want to be able to switch to another video after playing, how can I do it? Can I do this in another framework instead of flutter? Do you have any suggestions?

```
class Ilkanimas extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<Ilkanimas> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new SplashScreen(
        seconds: 8,
        navigateAfterSeconds: new HomePage(), //ikinci sayfaya yönlendirdik
        title: new Text(
          'Harun Yahya World',
          style: new TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,

              color: Colors.yellow,
              fontFamily: "GreatVibes-Regular",
              fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
              fontSize: 28.0),
        ),

        image: new Image.network(
            'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/book-7a285.appspot.com/o/ic_launcher.png?alt=media&token=605f6d54-7098-487c-ae4c-f70ae4476670'),
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(11, 8, 51,1.0),
        styleTextUnderTheLoader: new TextStyle(),
        photoSize: 100.0,
        onClick: () => print(""),
        loaderColor: Color.fromRGBO(11, 8, 51, 0.0));
  }
}
```

Comment: What you mean with another framework? New keyword is now optional in Dart. And I think IlkAnimasyon or FirstAnimation is better for your widget name.

Comment: I mean, let the video appear automatically instead of a picture